# Loop through the table and fetch the attribute of particular class only

Tags: jquery

This is my table , how can i get the **video-id** for class **newvideos** only

```
<table class="mytable2 table" id="videosexistingtable">
   <tbody class="connectedSortable ui-sortable">
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Video</th>
      </tr>
      <tr video-id="6" tag-id="1" class="newvideos" style="display: table-row;">
         <td>Video1</td>
         <td>Data Science</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="existingvideos" video-id="2">
         <td>Video2</td>
         <td>Data Science</td>
      </tr>
      <tr video-id="49" tag-id="1" class="newvideos" style="display: table-row;">
         <td>Video49</td>
         <td>Data Science</td>
      </tr>
      <tr video-id="48" tag-id="1" class="newvideos" style="display: table-row;">
         <td>Video48</td>
         <td>Data Science</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    getallnewvideos();
});

function getallnewvideos() {
    $("#videosexistingtable > tbody  > tr .newvideos").each(function() {
        var video_id = $(this).attr('video-id');
        console.log('video_id' + video_id);
    });
}
```

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/161/

Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `video-id` is not a valid attribute for the `tr` element. To store custom data in an element use a `data-*` attribute.

From there the issue is with your selector - you don't need the space between the `tr` and `.newvideos`. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  getallnewvideos();
});

function getallnewvideos() {
  $("#videosexistingtable > tbody > tr.newvideos").each(function() {
    var video_id = $(this).data('video-id'); // Note the use of data() here
    console.log('video_id: ' + video_id);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mytable2 table" id="videosexistingtable">
  <tbody class="connectedSortable ui-sortable">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Video</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-video-id="6" data-tag-id="1" class="newvideos">
      <td>Video1</td>
      <td>Data Science</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-video-id="2" class="existingvideos">
      <td>Video2</td>
      <td>Data Science</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-video-id="49" data-tag-id="1" class="newvideos">
      <td>Video49</td>
      <td>Data Science</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-video-id="48" data-tag-id="1" class="newvideos">
      <td>Video48</td>
      <td>Data Science</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternatively, you can build an array of the `video-id` by using `map()`:

```
var arr = $("#videosexistingtable > tbody > tr.newvideos").map(function() {
    return $(this).data('video-id');
}).get();
```

Comment: thanks working fine . , is it a problem if i use attributes instead of data as you mentioned ?? The code is working fine , should i change it ?

Comment: Yes you should change it. Invalid HTML can cause issues with JS and accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the space between **tr** and **.newvideos**

```
   $("#videosexistingtable > tbody  > tr.newvideos").each(function()
   {
        var video_id = $(this).attr('video-id');
        console.log('video_id'+video_id);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are too close buddy. just a small error in script line

```
    $("#videosexistingtable > tbody  > tr.newvideos").each(function()
```

please replace it "tr.newvideos" mistake is here